I'm setting a cookie from a React Native Android application, but then when I inspect the browser's cookies, I can't see the cookie I set
I have a React Native Android application in which I am setting a cookie this way:
        CookieManager.set('http://localhost:5000', {
            name: 'X-Auth',
            value: 'sdg1s6g1sd65f1a65s1fas6gs1d65a1s1hj51jtjgd6fgs',
            version: '1',
            expires: '2025-05-30T12:30:00.00-05:00',
        })
            .then((done) => {
                console.log('CookieManager.set =>', done);
            })

The cookie seems to be created successfully as I enter the then block. Afterwards, I open my Android emulator device's Google Chrome and go to http://localhost:5000 where my web app is located.
Then I open Google Chrome on my MacBook and go to chrome://inspect/#devices from where I inspect the Emulator's Google Chrome. Afterwards I navigate to "Application" in the dev tools and then open the cookies where I can't really see the cookie that I have set.
Am I misunderstanding how cookies work? I imagine that since I'm setting the cookie for http://localhost:5000 which is my Web application's URL, the cookie would be available there.
